# Rule of 72 binomial

Tags: calculus, finance, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Rule of 72?

So you have to work out the time it takes for an investment to double. With interest rate = x

So I get:

(1+x)^n = 2

Then I get how the 72 rule is formed through solving for n, giving n = ln2/x which is where the 72 comes from. As well as following the wiki page with Taylor series too.

But how would I go about showing the 72 rule through binomial expansion?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking.  What, precisely, is the rule of 72?  Where do you see a 72 in the formula $\ln(2)/x$?  How have you "shown" the rule of 72?  What do you mean by "showing the 72 rule through binomial expansion"?  Can you please edit your question to make it more clear?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_72. The rule is used in finance as a quick way to calculate how many years it will take for an investment to double. if you take the formula, then the ln of each side, then rearrange for n. Ln(1+x) is approx to x  so it becomes n=72/x.

Comment: My point is not that I can't Google "Rule of 72," but that your question should be self-contained.  The reader should not *have* to Google your question in order to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a loose derivation. Starting with $\left(1+\frac r{100}\right)^t = 2,$ the binomial theorem gives us
$$1 + t\frac r{100} + \frac{t(t-1)}2\left(\frac r{100}\right)^2 \approx 2$$

This is a quadratic in $t$; using the quadratic formula and simplifying the resulting fraction, we get
$$t \approx -\frac{100}r + \frac12 + \sqrt{\frac{30\ 000}{r^2} - \frac{100}r + \frac14}$$

Now, since $r$ is small, the expression in the square root is dominated by its first term, so
$$\begin{align}
t &\approx -\frac{100}r + \frac12 + \sqrt{\frac{30\ 000}{r^2}}\\
&= -\frac{100}r + \frac12 + \frac{100\sqrt3}r\\
&= \frac12 + \frac{100}r(\sqrt3-1)\\
&= \frac12 + \frac{73.2\ldots}r
\end{align}$$
which is close enough to $\frac{72}r$.

The above calculation involved a certain disregard for accuracy, but since the "rule of 72" is fairly loose anyway, then no harm done.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense but where did the 30000 come from?

Comment: @chocolatekeyboard You're welcome. Let's write $R = \frac r{100}$ to keep things simple. Then the quadratic equation is
$$t^2\left(\frac {R^2}2\right) + t\left(R - \frac{R^2}2\right) - 1 \approx 0$$
whence
$$t \approx \frac{\cdots + \sqrt{\left(R - \frac{R^2}2\right)^2 + 2R^2}}{\cdots}$$
You can see that there will be a $3R^2$ term; this is where $30\ 000$ comes from (since $R = \frac r{100}$).

Answer (score 0):

the rule of $72$ is a heuristic, and not a hard and fast rule of mathematics.

$(1+ x)^n = 2 \implies xn \approx 72\%$

e.g. $(1.08)^9 = 1.999$

What is the math?

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+ \frac xn)^n = e^x$

When $n$ is large, and $nx = \ln 2\approx 0.69$, $(1+ x)^n = 2$

But for smaller values of $n$

$(1+ x)^n =$$ 1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!} x^3 + \cdots\\
1 + nx + \frac 12(1 - \frac{1}n) (nx)^2 + \frac 1{3!}(1-\frac 1n)(1-\frac 2n) (nx)^3 + \cdots$
$e^{nx} = 1 + nx + \frac 12 (nx)^2+ \frac 1{3!} (nx)^3+\cdots\\
(1+ x)^n < e^{nx}$

For finite $n, (1 +x)^n=2 \implies nx > \ln 2$